# Как упростить запрос?

Tags: mysql

```
$post = $this->db->fetch_array_all(
  "SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 10;"
);

$type_1 = $this->db->fetch_array_all(
  "SELECT
     COUNT(*)
   FROM
     `smile` 
   WHERE
     `post_id` = ".$this->db->quote_($this->id)." AND
     `enabled` = 1 AND `type_smile` = 1;");

$type_2 = $this->db->fetch_array_all(
  "SELECT
     COUNT(*)
   FROM
     `smile`
   WHERE
     `post_id` = ".$this->db->quote_($this->id)." AND
     `enabled` = 1 AND `type_smile` = 2;");

$type_3 = $this->db->fetch_array_all(
  "SELECT
     COUNT(*)
   FROM
     `smile`
   WHERE
     `post_id` = ".$this->db->quote_($this->id)." AND
     `enabled` = 1 AND `type_smile` = 3;");
```

Можно ли не отправлять 3 запроса, а выполнить 1 и чтобы ни сказывалось на производительности

У каждого поста есть 3 смайла:

- :) это хорошо
- -) это нормально
- :( это плохо

Все голосуют в итоге потом на главной странице нужно будет вывести заголовок поста и 3 смайла с цифрой голосов у каждого смайла, причем пост тоже является смайлом и его нужно будет учитывать

В итоге считаем

Допустим на странице нужно вывести 10 последних тем, для каждой темы нужно вывести смайлы и того получается 30 запросов!!!

Как можно упростить?

Вот так будет выглядеть

http://pixs.ru/showimage/testpng_4257106_9084930.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
sum(case `type_smile` when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as type1,
sum(case `type_smile` when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as type2,
sum(case `type_smile` when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as type3
FROM `smile` WHERE `post_id` = ".$this->db->quote_($this->id)." AND `enabled` = 1
```

Comment: А почему не просто:

    sum(if(`type_smile` = 1, 1, 0)) as type1,

? :)

Comment: Потому что еще есть тип 2 и тип 3

Comment: Я про использование IF вместо громоздкого CASE.

И вообще, я придираюсь :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  smyle.type_smile,
  COUNT(*) AS count_of_smiles
FROM
  post
INNER JOIN
  smile 
ON
  smile.post_id = post.id
WHERE
  smile.enabled = 1
GROUP BY
  smile.type_smile
ORDER BY
  count_of_smiles DESC
```